# Issue with XML in Eclipse Glassfish project. "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed."

Tags: xml, eclipse, glassfish

I got the "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document
type declaration must be well-formed." error message when writing glassfish-web.xml file for my glassfish project.

here my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
 <class-loader delegate="true"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this message, and when?

Comment: @nitind, right after I typed in the code it's underlined with red line and display that message (see screenshot).

Comment: When you save it, are there corresponding entries in the Problems view? And so they go away when you close the editor?

Comment: @nitind, when I just press Ctrl+S the problem stays at its place. When I close editor entry removes from Problems view.

Comment: @nitind, I just follow instructions from Peter Späth - Beginning Jakarta EE. Here fragment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJYIOX2JXXdtWRzILxFJVDuQSOaIipVA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do they come back when you reopen the file?

Comment: @nitind, yep they do

Comment: Reasonable certain they're coming from the LemMinX language server, through Wild Web Developer being installed. Odds are its because the system location redirects to a web page rather than the DTD contents.

Comment: @nitind, loading dtd from localhost helped me

Comment: @penny what exactly did you do to solve this problem

Comment: @mouad36 easy way: download dtd somewhere and point to it in XML snippet; right way: read dtd and xsl specifications how to handle unreachable files